# Naming files and writing to them in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am still learning python and need some help - go easy!

I need to ask a user to name the file to be saved and then write to it with a set of information in the file depending on the info stored in the model.  So far I can create  a file name but not open and write into it:

```
file_name = input("please enter the name of the saved file:")
saved_file = file_name + ".txt"
file = open (saved_file, "w")
file.write(str(file_write))
```

file_write is pre-defined at the start of the program as:

```
file_write = "Generation ", new_gen ,"Juvenile population ", pop_j ,"adult population ", pop_a ,"senile population ", pop_s ,"total population ", pop_total
```

Hope this makes sense and remember...go easy on me!

EDIT - This does not come up with an error.  The problem is the file is created but the text to write in it does not appear.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When something you tried is "not working", it is often useful to include the error message or undesired output that you get.

Comment: Do you get an error? Your code as posted should work in python3. file_write is a tuple so calling str is going to write the data wrapped in parens, what is your expected output?

Comment: Hi - no error comes up, the file is created but nothing is saved into the document.  Thought that was clear in OP!! Sorry if it has broken house rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from your message (you should always include the output you get, whether it is not the desired one or an error message), I think your code is working but not writing the desired output to your file.

This is because you are not defining `file_write` correctly. The way you do it (separating objects with a comma), `file_write` is a tuple (which you can see running `type(file_write)`).

Instead, you should do:

```
file_write = "Generation {}, Juvenile population {}".format(new_gen, pop_j) 
# limiting myself to 2 values for concision
```

then `type(file_write)` is `str` and the rest of your code should work fine.

Comment: He used 'str' on it before writing, though.

Comment: @XamuelSchulman Yes, but str() was called on a tuple, so as Padraic C pointed out, OP might be getting an output separated by string. As I said, I'm only guessing what the issue is here ; OP should edit is post to include the error/output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply - for the  type(file_write) is str bit, does this go under the file_write = "Generation {},etc section or replace the file.write part in my code?

Comment: Do not include type(file_write) in your code; it's only something you can use temporarily (e.g. in a print) to determine the type of your object

Comment: Great, its working - thanks for your help!